# Run-time Error: Unable to set the FormulaArray property of the Range Class

Tags: excel, vba

I get the run-time error 1004: unable to set the FormulaArray property of the Range class. I have been researching this problem but I can't find a solution to it. It is not longer than 255 character. I am trying to put the formula in a new table column too, so maybe that is part of the problem.

Could the problem be the "Rows(R8C:RC)" Portion I am trying to make this a relative reference so that it will reference to the table the formula is in?

When I "debug.print Trans_ID" I get the correct code but maybe the R8C:RC is not changing to the correct cell reference.

```
Dim Trans_ID As String

'AccountNumber is equal to 1003

Trans_ID = "=IFERROR(INDEX(Journal,SMALL(IF(L_" & AccountNumber & _
     "=Journal[Acct. '#],Journal[Trans ID],""""),ROWS(R8C:RC)),MATCH(Ledger_" & _
     AccountNumber & "[[#Headers],[Trans ID]],Journal[#Headers],0)),"""")"


Worksheets("Ledger").ListObjects(NewTableName.Name).ListColumns( _
                   "Trans ID").DataBodyRange.FormulaArray = Trans_ID
```

This will return a single number. It works when I enter enter the formula in not using VBA.

Comment: Have you tried replacing the R1C1 notation with A1 notation and see how that goes?

Comment: I have tried that. I changed it to "C$8:C8" but it still doesn't work. When I do that and debug.print it puts the R8C:RC back into it.

Comment: If you write an array formula to the entire column I don't think the row number will update, I think you have to fill down after writing to the first cell.

Comment: I did this and it worked correctly.

`
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ledger").Cells(8, LedgerAccountCell +  _
           9).Select
                
Selection.FormulaArray = Trans_ID
`

Comment: Does this throw an error: `Worksheets("Ledger").ListObjects(NewTableName.Name).ListColumns( _
                   "Trans ID").DataBodyRange.Cells(1).FormulaArray = Trans_ID`?

Comment: @BigBen That was the problem It worked once I put it in the top cell and then filled the formula to the rest of the table column. I used this formula, I don't know if it is the best way or not:

```Worksheets("Ledger").ListObjects(NewTableName.Name).ListColumns
                   "Trans ID").DataBodyRange.FillDown```

Comment: That works quite well paired with writing the formula into the first cell.

Comment: That does give me a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem boils down to setting the `Range.FormulaArray` property, I refer to my research following this query, kindly commented on by Tim Williams:
[Autocomplete formulas when inserting table row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76839403/autocomplete-formulas-when-inserting-table-row/77326647#77326647) and which I reproduce below:

After several trial and error tests, I came to the following conclusions:

- Although the official documentation on `Range.FormulaArray` https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/api/excel.range.formulaarray says that this property is read/write, it actually does not allow its direct modification, but it can be modified indirectly as shown below.
- When cells in the range have different formulas, the value of `Range.FormulaArray` is `Null`.
- The only way to modify `Range.FormulaArray` is to give the same formula to all cells in the range, for example by modifying `Range.Formula = "=..."` or `Range.FormulaLocal = "=..."` when the language is not English. This gives the `Range.FormulaArray` property the same value given to formulas in all cells in the range.
- Once the range has the non-null `.FormulaArray` property set, you can, for example, insert or add rows to a table (`ListObject`) and the calculated column will automatically take the formula set in `.ListObject.ListColumns(c).DataBodyRange.FormulaArray`

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35155593)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Paul. I follow your advice and include the full explanation. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

Relative references won't update if you try to write an array formula to multiple cells. Able to reproduce your error, albeit with a much simpler array formula. `Range.FillDown` should work though if you write the formula into the first cell.

```
With Worksheets("Ledger").ListObjects(NewTableName.Name).ListColumns("Trans ID").DataBodyRange
    .Cells(1).FormulaArray = Trans_ID
    .FillDown
End With
```

If you already have the formulas set to autofill in the table, the `.FillDown` is redundant.