# VBA FormulaArray pulling data from one table to another

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, formula

I have two tables. Table1 is on another sheet, where I'm trying to pull the data, Table2 is on the Header sheet, where I'm putting the data. It's an array formula, where the data will be placed over multiple cells. This seems to be where I'm getting stuck. I can't seem to get it to paste, giving me a "1004 error" (if not using databodyrange) and "method or data member not found" (if using ListColumn).

Value Bought Tracker is on the Header page
FinalTableSource[Buy Value] is on the second page

Here it is now with some updated code, but I'm still getting a 1004 error.

```
Public Sub MakeFinalTable_Click()
'Resize Table

Dim ws As Worksheet, lo As ListObject

Set ws = Sheets("Header")
Set lo = ws.ListObjects("FinalTable")

lo.ListColumns("Value Bought Tracker").DataBodyRange.FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(INDEX(FinalTableSource[Buy Value],SMALL(IF(FinalTableSource[Buy Value]<>"",ROW(FinalTableSource[Buy Value])-ROW(INDEX(FinalTableSource[Buy Value],1,1))+1),ROWS(AA$4:AA4))),"""")"

End Sub
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Can you paste that exact same formula manually?

Comment: I can. It works perfectly if I paste it manually in the cell. But because I'm trying to speed up the sheet, I'd rather do a bunch of calculations, then push the macro to make the final table.

Comment: ListColumns is not a property of a `Worksheet` object - are you missing a listobject reference?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, lo as ListObject

Set ws = Sheets("Header")
Set lo = ws.ListObjects(1)

lo.ListColumns("Value Bought Tracker").DataBodyRange.FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(INDEX(FinalTableSource[Buy Value],SMALL(IF(FinalTableSource[Buy Value]<>"",ROW(FinalTableSource[Buy Value])-ROW(INDEX(FinalTableSource[Buy Value],1,1))+1),ROWS(AA$4:AA4))),"")"
```

Edit: break your lines down so there's only one thing going on in each line; then you can more-easily see where the problem is -

```
Public Sub MakeFinalTable_Click()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, lo As ListObject, lc As ListColumn, rng As Range

    Set ws = Sheets("Header")
    Set lo = ws.ListObjects("FinalTable")
    Set lc = lo.ListColumns("Value Bought Tracker")
    Set rng = lc.DataBodyRange

    rng.FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(INDEX(FinalTableSource[Buy Value]," & _
                       "SMALL(IF(FinalTableSource[Buy Value]<>""""," & _
                       "ROW(FinalTableSource[Buy Value])-" & _
                       "ROW(INDEX(FinalTableSource[Buy Value],1,1))+1),ROWS(AA$4:AA4))),"""")"

End Sub
```

Comment: That seems to have gotten me closer. It's nowsaying "Subscript out of range", with this code.

`
Dim ws As Worksheet, lo As ListObject

Set ws = Sheets("Header")
Set lo = ws.ListObjects(FinalTable)

lo.ListColumns("Value Bought Tracker").DataBodyRange.FormulaArray = "code as follows"
`

Comment: You can update your question if you have follow-on code to add.  Also - be sure to note which line is giving you the error.

Comment: Maybe `Set lo = ws.ListObjects("FinalTable")`  ?

Comment: I've updated my question to show the full current code.

Comment: It would be the "lo.ListColumns("Value Bought Tracker")" line

Comment: See my edit above - helps to narrow your lines of code down to only one thing at a time.

Comment: Still a 1004 error. Could this be happening because FinalTableSource is on a second page? Not Header?

Comment: 1004 on which line?

Comment: Still the formula array code. I can't figure out what section of the code is breaking. It works up till that point.

Comment: `[Buy Value]<>""` should be `[Buy Value]<>""""` you need to escape the quotes there.  Sorry I missed that earlier.

Comment: I made sure to adjust that before. Sorry, I'll update the code above to show that.

Comment: Maybe try the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58120700/run-time-error-unable-to-set-the-formulaarray-property-of-the-range-class   Write the formula to the first cell then fill down.

Comment: TIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIM!!!!! Whoever you are, you beautiful! That fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the operation of `Range.FormulaArray` is not well explained in the documentation. I transfer the results of my research on this property ([Autocomplete formulas when inserting table row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76839403/autocomplete-formulas-when-inserting-table-row/76839509#76839509)):

- Although the official documentation on `Range.FormulaArray` https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/api/excel.range.formulaarray says that this property is read/write, it actually does not allow its direct modification, but it can be modified indirectly as shown below.
- When cells in the range have different formulas, the value of `Range.FormulaArray` is `Null`.
- The only way to modify `Range.FormulaArray` is to give the same formula to all cells in the range, for example by modifying `Range.Formula = "=..."` or `Range.FormulaLocal = "=..."` when the language is not English. This gives the `Range.FormulaArray` property the same value given to formulas in all cells in the range.
- Once the range has the non-null `.FormulaArray` property set, you can, for example, insert or add rows to a table (`ListObject`) and the calculated column will automatically take the formula set in `.ListObject.ListColumns(c).DataBodyRange.FormulaArray`