# Autocomplete formulas when inserting table row

Tags: excel, vba, listobject

File > Options > Proofing > AutoCorrect Options > Fill Formulas in tables to create calculated columns, determines if when writing a formula in a cell of a table, this formula will also be written in the rest of the cells of that column of the table. If the option is activated and all the cells in the column are empty, the formula is copied to the rest of the cells.

But if the option is deactivated or any cell in the column already contains some data, then the formula is not automatically copied to the rest of the cells in the column, but an icon appears that allows us to choose whether the formula is copied or not.

However, whether the option is checked or not, and even if not all cells are blank in the column, when you INSERT A ROW into the table, the formulas in the new row are always filled automatically.

I had thought this was due to the value of .FormulaArray for the column range. However this is not determinative, because .FormulaArray stores the value of the formula when the entire range has the same formula, but is null if any cell in the range has a different formula. Therefore .ListColumns(c).DataBodyRange.FormulaArray does not determine whether the default formula of a table field will be copied when inserting a new row.

The question I am asking, then, is where is that value of the default formula associated with each column of a table (ListObject) stored? And also, why in some cases, when inserting a new row, some columns take the default formula and others don't?

Because I can't find a causal relationship that justifies it, since there are columns that have different formulas and values in their cells and still, when inserting a new row, they take a default formula (the formula that was first introduced in the column), while other columns are not assigned any formula.

I know it's a very technical and formal question, but I would appreciate if someone has the explanation, because i'm stuck at my job. Thank you all. All the best.

I have tried to enter data with the column completely empty and with some cells occupied. This determines when .FormulaArray is null and when it is not. But when inserting rows, some fields autofill formulas and others don't, and I can't figure out what the difference is.

Answer (score 2):

After several trial and error tests, I came to the following conclusions:

- Although the official documentation on `Range.FormulaArray` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.formulaarray says that this property is read/write, it actually does not allow its direct modification, but it can be modified indirectly as shown below.
- When cells in the range have different formulas, the value of `Range.FormulaArray` is `Null`.
- The only way to modify `Range.FormulaArray` is to give the same formula to all cells in the range, for example by modifying the range formula, that is:
  `Range.Formula = "=..."` or `Range.FormulaLocal = "=..."` when the language is not English. This gives the `Range.FormulaArray` property the same value given to formulas in all cells in the range using `Range.Formula`.
- Once the range has the non-null `.FormulaArray` property set, you can, for example, insert or add rows to a table (list object) and the calculated column will automatically take the formula set in `.ListObject.ListColumns(c).DataBodyRange.FormulaArray`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there may not be any VBA property exposed for this, but there is a `TableColumn.CalculatedColumnFormula` property in the  `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet` object model:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.tablecolumn.calculatedcolumnformula?view=openxml-2.8.1

If you unzip an Excel file with a listobject which has a pre-defined formula assigned to a list column, you can see it there (I got this from `listobject1.xml` for example):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<table xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="xr xr3" 
xmlns:xr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2014/revision" xmlns:xr3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2016/revision3" id="3" 
xr:uid="{4BC10EFA-3170-4F60-865C-90CE4562C734}" name="Table3" displayName="Table3" ref="A1:G18" totalsRowShown="0"><autoFilter ref="A1:G18" 
xr:uid="{4BC10EFA-3170-4F60-865C-90CE4562C734}"/>
<tableColumns count="7">
   <tableColumn id="1" xr3:uid="{EBC090AD-7675-48CC-945A-DAB4FC16438B}" 
name="Col0001"/>
   <tableColumn id="2" xr3:uid="{D2C68174-33C4-4917-9394-D75590CB1510}" name="Col0002"/>
   <tableColumn id="3" xr3:uid="{9506BA3E-94FB-46F4-9CD7-C4B9B27257F9}" name="Col0003"/>
   <tableColumn id="4" xr3:uid="{17CAF190-27B3-47E7-A3C0-961A01DD85F4}" name="Col0004"/>
   <tableColumn id="5" xr3:uid="{256C70AC-6327-410C-AC87-DCD6815B4CDE}" name="Col0005"/>
   <tableColumn id="6" xr3:uid="{E70A6FB0-2F5A-4226-8173-85088B227273}" name="Col0006"/>
   <tableColumn id="7" xr3:uid="{F6346482-77CB-4CED-B717-FFB314B03774}" name="Col0007" dataDxfId="0">
       <calculatedColumnFormula>ROW()</calculatedColumnFormula>
   </tableColumn>
</tableColumns>
<tableStyleInfo name="TableStyleMedium2" showFirstColumn="0" showLastColumn="0" showRowStripes="1" showColumnStripes="0"/>
</table>
```

Comment: Extremely grateful, Tim. I didn't even know the OpenXml format, nor do I know how to unzip an .xml file, but I understand what you're saying: <calculatedColumnFormula>ROW()</calculatedColumnFormula> within a <tableColumn declaration establishes the calculated formula for said column.
The question is, is there any way to modify this property in the .xml file? Thank you very much for taking the trouble to respond to my question. All the best.

Comment: You can "unzip" an Excel file (assuming .xlsx, .xmsm, etc) by adding .zip to its name and then double-clicking it: it will open like a regular Zip archive.   Then you can view/edit the files in that archive.